# How to create ionic apps using visual studio 2013 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a tutorial on how to build [ionic apps on visual studio](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-templates-for-visual-studio/)?

Have anyone used [ionic templates in VS](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b26474d5-c14d-4d69-bad5-37954538c506/view/Discussions)? When I try to open this template, I'm getting this error:

[image: Ionic template not installing]

> This extension is not installable on any of the currently installed products.

If I *download and install* through [VS 2013 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) templates (in new project dialogue) I get this error after creating the project:

[image: Issue after opening Ionic project]

> The imported (CordovaTools) project was not found

**Question:** How can I get those **.targets** files here which could not be found by VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because this template only support Visual Studio 2015 RC now but you are using VS 12.0 which is VS2013.

[**Update**]

Note: The following content may be moved to a blog or somewhere can be shared to others in the future.

**Environment**:

Tools: Visual Studio 2013 Update 4  + Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1

OS: Windows 8.1 pro

**Topic**: How to develop ionic starting from a template on https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs in Visual Studio 2013

Step 1:

Created a new blank Cordova App in Visual Studio 2013.

File->New->Project->JavaScript->Apache Cordova Apps -> Blank App (named TestIonicTemplate).

Step 2:

Download the template from https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs
Open the site http://code.ionicframework.com/# . We will use it later.

Step 3:

Let’s say the template folder is ionic-starter-tabs-master, and the project is TestIonicTemplate. Then start to merge things to the VS project.

1. Go to visual studio, add a new folder named templates under the
   root project folder.
2. Do the following copy-past: Move all .js files from
   \ionic-starter-tabs-master\js\ to TestIonicTemplate\scripts Move all
   html files from \ionic-starter-tabs-master\templates to
   TestIonicTemplate\templates
3. Go back to VS -> right click on the folders mentioned above ->
   add->existing items. After add these files, we have the following
   structure.

[image]

Step 4:

Do the following modification to the index.html of VS project based on the index.html in the template we downloaded.

1. Add reference to ionic.css and ionic.bundle.js We can choose using
   local copy or ionic CDN, you can get all of these from 
   http://code.ionicframework.com/# I mentioned before. I use CDN here.
2. Remove the reference to index.js and add reference to all .js we
   copied.
3. Copy the meta line from \ionic-starter-tabs-master\index.html
4. add 'ng-app="starter"' in the body and remove the default html
   element in body.
5. Copy the body content from \ionic-starter-tabs-master\index.html Now
   we have the following index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>TestIonicTemplate</title>

    <!-- TestIonicTemplate references -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the result I saw in ripple:

[image]

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 community. Doesn't it it support [Cordova](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/05/12/mobile-first-cloud-first-development-visual-studio-apache-cordova-tooling-and-cloud-optimized-net-futures.aspx)?

Comment: VS 2013 does support cordova. but the template you mentioned doesn't support VS 2013. Let me give you some steps about how to create ionic cordova app later. I don't have a dev environment on hand now.

Comment: You got my point man!! I'm not concerned with the template. I needed to use VS to build ionic app. Thanks a loads!!

Answer (score 2):

I dont' quite understand your question, but you can use Visual Studio Code (VSC) for the development of Ionic apps and other web related project, it already comes with angular plugins.

If you mean that if VS can create Ionic Projects, I don't think that is possible. Create it through the CMD/Terminal

- npm install -g cordova ionic
- ionic start myApp tabs
- cd myApp
- ionic platform add ios (or android)
- ionic build ios (or android)
- ionic emulate ios (or android)

and then open it through your favorite IDE or text editor to start developing.

Comment: Yes, I understand @JosephOcasio. This is what I have done through the [guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/starting.html). I'm keen to see this template working.