# how to develop android app using ionic framework

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework

I want to develop app using visual studio in .NET platform. Can I use ionic framework to develop app in visual studio. If yes then please tell how to do it and tell how to install ionic framework and which are all the software we require to develop app using ionic framework..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop cross-platform Hybrid apps in Visual Studio using Ionic...

1.Download & Install Visual Studio Community it is recommended by ionic itself for developers using Windows.

2.Download "**Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova**" officially from here
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-vs.aspx

with that you can build apps for iOS, Android, and Windows using web technologies.

2.Run the setup & click Install for the products shown.

3.Go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates inside Visual Studio and in the Online tab search for Ionic and install it.

4.Now you can start a new project and select the Ionic project template, give your project a name and wait for Visual Studio to do the rest.

Comment: do u know how to use the ionic templates after installing it in visual studios ??

Comment: i want to develop ionic frames using visual studio.. how to start the project??

Comment: first of all you didn't accept answer for your previous question, you did behaved rude.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31017417/4034209 and accept my answer here as it was helpful

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept that answer as the best one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use node's package manager (npm) to install the ionic framework.

```
$ npm install -g ionic
```

For absolute beginners a startertemplate should be used.

Have a look here for more detailed informations:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic

Of course you need a text editor, and a browser comes pretty handy too.

Comment: Schults dude im trieng to use ionic framework using visual studio, i know to use it with the text editor and command prompt. Do u have any idea about using it with visual studio??